# /x/search routes to x#show instead of x#search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, routes

I am at a loss with rails routing.
´$.ajax -> lh:3000/nodes/search?q=blabla&_=1411073392872´
routes to Nodes#show and obviously fails there because show would require something like /nodes/3/ with the id to work.

rake routes

```
welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)       welcome#index
           root GET    /                              welcome#index
          nodes GET    /nodes(.:format)               nodes#index
                POST   /nodes(.:format)               nodes#create
       new_node GET    /nodes/new(.:format)           nodes#new
      edit_node GET    /nodes/:id/edit(.:format)      nodes#edit
           **node GET    /nodes/:id(.:format)           nodes#show**
                PATCH  /nodes/:id(.:format)           nodes#update
                PUT    /nodes/:id(.:format)           nodes#update
                DELETE /nodes/:id(.:format)           nodes#destroy

  edges_to_node GET    /nodes/:id/toedges(.:format)   nodes#searchtoedges
edges_from_node GET    /nodes/:id/fromedges(.:format) nodes#searchfromedges
   search_edges GET    /edges/search(.:format)        edges#search
   **search_nodes GET    /nodes/search(.:format)        nodes#search**
```

in routes.rb I got this

```
resources :nodes
resources :edges
get 'nodes/:id/toedges', to: 'nodes#searchtoedges', as: 'edges_to_node'
get 'nodes/:id/fromedges', to: 'nodes#searchfromedges', as: 'edges_from_node' 
get '/edges/search', to: 'edges#search', as: 'search_edges'
**get '/nodes/search', to: 'nodes#search', as: 'search_nodes'**
```

All the other routes work especially those searchtoedges ones. I use the /nodes/search in an ajax call if that is important. The response to the ajax is a RecordNotFound exception complaining that no id is there in the show action. So for some reason it routes to ´/nodes/:id(.:format) => nodes#show´. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routes match from the top down. The first route that matches `/nodes/search` is your show route, with an id of `"search"`.

Move your custom `get /nodes/search` route *above* your `resources :nodes` line so that a GET request for `/nodes/search` is matched by the intended route.

Alternatively, add it to your resources declaration:

```
resources :nodes do
  collection { get 'search' }
end
```